# How do you create a module of an enum?

Tags: typescript, import, enums, module, extend

[Tests ground](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-playground-nbemq?file=/src/index.ts)

I am trying to add a compile-time value to an existing enum.
The base is in `src/abc.ts`

```
export enum Test {
  a,
  b,
  c
}
```

and the module is in `src/def.ts`

```
import { Test } from "./abc";

declare module "./abc" {
  export enum Test {
    d = 3,
    e = 4,
    f
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to log the `Test` enum in `src/index.ts`

```
import { Test } from "./abc";
import "./def";

console.log(Test);
```

The editor's autocomplete finds the three additionnal enum values (suggest them in the autocomplete list)
but when you run the script, only the default

```
Object {…}
0: "a"
1: "b"
2: "c"
a: 0
b: 1
c: 2
```

values are logged! `d`,`e`,`f` are missing.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are amending only type definition, but not the value. Typescript generates object for the enum, something like:

```
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    Test[Test["a"] = 0] = "a";
    Test[Test["b"] = 1] = "b";
    Test[Test["c"] = 2] = "c";
})(Test || (Test = {}));
```

So you'll need to add the new properties to this object:

```
const enumObject: any = Test;
enumObject[enumObject["d"] = 3] = "d";
enumObject[enumObject["e"] = 4] = "e";
enumObject[enumObject["f"] = 5] = "f";
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-playground-yk53q?file=/src/def.ts)